# How can you force recompilation of a single file in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools

The idea is that a project has a single file with `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in it. It might be cool to have it recompiled without explicitly changing its modification date.

edit: $(shell touch -c ..) might be a good solution if only clumsy.

Comment: This may be the wrong solution to your problem. Some versioning tools can dump out details of the version of your source. A bit of script hackery in your build process and those details get built into your code. Doesn't matter if you have to check out the source and re-build in ten years time - your version info will still reflect the details for that tag.

Comment: @Steve314: more likely he wants an about box that mentions the build number and build date.

Comment: @Ken - if so, the versioning tool trick is the right way. There's no reason why the script hackery can't place the version details into the code (or resource file) for an about box, and getting a build number into an about box probably needs easily-forgotten manual intervention otherwise. Neither make, the compiler, nor the filesystem knows your build number.

Comment: Dumping the version info with an external tool? That doesn't sound very multiplatform. What's the tool that does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard idiom is to have the object file (not the source file!) depend on a target which doesn't exist and has no rules or dependencies (this target is conventionally called FORCE), like this

```
always-recompile.o: FORCE
FORCE:
```

This will break if a file named "FORCE" gets created somehow, though.  With GNU make you can instead use the special target .PHONY, which doesn't have this limitation, but does require you to have an explicit rule to rebuild that file:

```
always-recompile.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o always-recompile.o always-recompile.c

.PHONY: always-recompile.o
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html for more details.

Comment: You should do ".PHONY: FORCE" because always-recompile.o is not a phony target. With ".PHONY: FORCE" it should not matter if a file called FORCE gets created.

Comment: Does that actually work?  The GNU make manual sounds like phony targets don't work as dependencies of real targets.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to delete the corresponding object file (`.o` or `.obj`) before running `make`. This will trigger a recompile (and relink) without changing the source file modification date.